# How to run some function during installation of a moodle block?

Tags: php, moodle

I am just wondering if there is any way to run some custom function when a block is being installed? I can see that there is after_installation() function used in a block, but there is no function declaration in the super class block_base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In db/install.php (inside your block's folder) put a function called xmldb_block_BLOCKNAME_install(). You should probably return true at the end of this, but I'd have to double check to see if that is required.

You can put whatever you want inside the function. This works for all different plugin types in Moodle.

Comment: Thanks a lot davo smith. I have another question related to this: Is this possible to prevent the block being installed if there is a error? Say, I want to call some functions during install.php, if those functions return error, the block will not be installed.

Comment: Not really - the database tables from install.xml have already been created by that point (although I'm not sure about the capabilities in access.php - you'd have to check). The best you can do at this point is display a clear message about the error and ask the user to delete the plugin via the admin settings (which will delete the install.xml tables).